# jQuery trigger() stopPropagation() not working - bubbling occurring?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a site that has buttons that are generated dynamically.

I'm using jQuery to toggle classes of hidden elements `$('.toggle-button').on('click')` (i.e. off-canvas cart, sidebar, etc.) based on `data` attributes

I'm using `trigger('click')` for the dynamic buttons and passing data through to trigger the correct hidden element. The problem is `trigger()` is bubbling to other buttons that have class `toggle-button` or that's what I think the problem is...

I've tried `event.stopPropagation()` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm working with.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.toggle-button').on('click', function(event, triggerData){

    console.log('toggle button triggered');

    toggleClass = '';
    targetSelector = '';
    targetElement = '';

    if ( !triggerData ) {
      toggleClass = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
      targetSelector = $(this).attr('data-target');
    } else {
      toggleClass = triggerData.toggleClass;
      targetSelector = triggerData.targetSelector;
    }

    targetElement = $(targetSelector);
    targetElement.toggleClass(toggleClass);

  });

  $(document).on('click', '.view-cart', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('view cart button clicked');

    $('.toggle-button').trigger('click', {
      toggleClass : 'show',
      targetSelector : '.cart'
    });
  });
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.toggle-button').on('click', function(event, triggerData) {

    console.log('toggle button triggered');

    toggleClass = '';
    targetSelector = '';
    targetElement = '';

    if (!triggerData) {
      toggleClass = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
      targetSelector = $(this).attr('data-target');
    } else {
      toggleClass = triggerData.toggleClass;
      targetSelector = triggerData.targetSelector;
    }

    targetElement = $(targetSelector);
    targetElement.toggleClass(toggleClass);

  });

  $(document).on('click', '.view-cart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('view cart button clicked');

    $('.toggle-button').trigger('click', {
      toggleClass: 'show',
      targetSelector: '.cart'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.cart,
.info {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cart.show,
.info.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.product {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  text-align: center;
}

.product a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <button class="toggle-button" data-toggle="show" data-target=".cart">View Cart</button>

  <button class="toggle-button" data-toggle="show" data-target=".info">View Info</button>
  <hr>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <a href="/cart" class="view-cart">View Cart</a>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <a href="/cart" class="view-cart">View Cart</a>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <a href="/cart" class="view-cart">View Cart</a>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <a href="/cart" class="view-cart">View Cart</a>
  </div>

  <div class="cart">
    <span>This is your cart</span>
  </div>

  <div class="info">
    <span>This is additional info</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two `button` with class `toggle-button` ...whose click event is being triggered correctly - while the problem is, that probably only one of them should be triggered. either select the element to click by a combined `class` attribute or by `id` attribute. those events are not bubbling at all, the selector just matches two elements - and that's why it subsequently clicks onto two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two `.toggle-button` element, so `$('.toggle-button').trigger()` is running two times.

I recommend to name different class names of these basically.
But there is a other way not to do so, you can use `:first` selector as shown below.
https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.toggle-button').on('click', function(event, triggerData){

    console.log('toggle button triggered');

    toggleClass = '';
    targetSelector = '';
    targetElement = '';

    if ( !triggerData ) {
      toggleClass = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
      targetSelector = $(this).attr('data-target');
    } else {
      toggleClass = triggerData.toggleClass;
      targetSelector = triggerData.targetSelector;
    }

    targetElement = $(targetSelector);
    targetElement.toggleClass(toggleClass);

  });

  $(document).on('click', '.view-cart', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('view cart button clicked');

    $('.toggle-button:first').trigger('click', {
      toggleClass : 'show',
      targetSelector : '.cart'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: using a pseudo selector in indeed an alternative to a combined class.